# How to escape the closing bracket when doing string interpolation

Tags: bash

I want to `echo` the value of a variable or a default value if the variable is empty or not been set.

I tried:

```
echo "${X:-{}}"
```

Result:

> value}

if the value of X has been set or

> {}

if it is not set.

When the variable is set a closing bracket appears in my output, an undesirable behavior. How can I escape the closing bracket? (I tried escaping with "\", with no success... )

Comment: Use a variable for the replacement text to avoid confusing the parser? `def={}; echo "${X:-$def}"`

Comment: I was wondering if there was a more elegant method...

Comment: Not that I can see offhand. The parser is getting "confused" and ending early. Escaping might be an option but I don't think that's supported for `\}` as would be needed here. If you can deal with a default value of `'{}'` you could use `echo "${X:-'{}'}"`

Comment: @Etan Using a variable for the replacement text seems to work the best for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers work in `bash` (of the correct versions at least), `zsh` and `ksh` but appear not to work in at least some versions of `sh`.

Using a variable for the replacement should work everywhere I hope:

```
def={}
echo "${X:-$def}"
```

Answer (score 4):

This will do:

```
echo "${X:-"{}"}"
```

Comment: When I try this, my command prompt seems to expect some more input. I have to add an additional ". Still doesn't work in the case where X is set...

Comment: @Heschoon you sure you are in Bash? that behavior (expecting more input) is shown in sh. If Bash, then which version?

Comment: Ok, I was doing my commands in Boot2Docker, which doesn't use bash, this is the source of my problems.

Answer (score 3):

The parser thinks that the first `}` is closing the `${}`, so prints the variable, and then the second `}`.  You need to escape the first closing bracket:

```
echo "${z:-{\}}"
```

Comment: This results in `{\}` for unset variable here on bash 3 but seems to work for bash 4.

Comment: Returns `{\}` with `GNU bash, version 4.1.2`

Comment: Works for me with bash `4.3.33(1)-release` and works on ideone.com with  `4.3.30(1)-release`. Does fail on bash `4.1.2(1)-release` on CentOS 6 though. Also works on bash `4.2.45(1)-release` on CentOS 7.